# Remap End Key - $ Not Sufficient

Tags: vim

I am trying to get off of using the arrow keys to navigate in VIM, so that I dont have to move my hands off the home rows. The problem I am having is finding the End Key equivalent. I used it a ton to go to the end of a line. I can still use it, but then I have to move my hands off the home rows, making this adjustment pointless. $ moves my cursor to the last character in the line, not after the last character in the line, which is where I want it to go. Why would I want to insert right before the last character on the line?

How can I remap the functionality of End Key (which can be used in insert and visual mode) to something else?

Thank you

Comment: If you want to insert something at the end of the current line, use `A`

Comment: You *can't* move after the last character in a line; the cursor is always on top of some character (and the implicit newline at the end of a line doesn't count). That's (probably) part of the reason that vi[m] distinguishes between "insert" and "append".

Comment: @KeithThompson You *can* move after the last character in a line: see `:h 'virtualedit'`.

Comment: @ZyX: Ah, I should have known that vim would break my assumptions. By default, though, the cursor can't move past the last character in a line (unless the line is empty).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are doing `$i` which is the wrong approach.

`$` is the right command to reach the end of the line but `i` is used to enter insert mode **before** the current character. You are supposed to use `a` to enter insert mode **after** the current character.

So you seem to be blocked because you don't know about `a` which is just as basic as `i`, IMO.

`$a` would solve your immediate problem.

But there's more, did you know that you can use `I` to enter insert mode at the beginning of the line? What command could we use to enter insert mode *at the end of the line*?

You are right, the correct command to enter insert mode at the end of the line is simply `A`, as @dusan commented.

You don't need to remap anything. What you need is a second (first?) injection of `$ vimtutor`.

Comment: Great answer! Never heard of vimtutor, but will give it a try now. Thanks!